# Unable to change lock screen wallpaper

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, lock-screen

I am unable to change my lock screen wallpaper.  It just keeps going back to the one I set way before or the default wallpaper with green mountains.

The usual way of changing the lock screen wallpaper in Windows 10 is by going to **Settings**, and going to **Personalization**, then clicking **Lock screen** at the left pane.  After doing that, this screen should appear:

[image: Lock Screen Background Settings Screen]

If I choose a picture from **Choose your picture**, let's say I picked the third one, it sets the picture to the one I set way before I updated Windows 10.

[image: Lock Screen Background reverted to the picture I set before]

However, when I select **Windows Spotlight** from the Background options, it sets the picture to the one with the green mountains and what appears to be a lake.

[image: Lock Screen Background changed to green mountains]

If I click on the **Browse** button, it showed a window where I can pick a picture for the lock screen, which it would normally do.  However, when I already selected the picture I want, the preview will just show a gray background and a spinner that spins forever.

[image: Lock Screen Background Preview shows a gray background and a spinner that spins forever]

This is extremely odd, because I can change my lock screen wallpaper on an earlier version of Windows 10.

I looked it up online, and saw that others were experiencing this issue too.

I already tried various fixes I found online:

1. **`sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`**

   - It doesn't solve my problem.
2. **[Take ownership of `SystemData` folder](https://www.askvg.com/fix-cant-change-lock-screen-background-and-user-account-picture-in-windows-8/)**

   - I have tried it before and it does nothing.
3. **[Remove everything on `[HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen]`, then take ownership of `SystemData` folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-change-lock-screen-image-in-windows-10/ab09358e-8bfb-43f9-a7b4-bd74536197e8?page=4)**

   - Still no.
4. **[Make changes in Group Policy and run `gpupdate /force`](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-change-lock-screen-image-in-windows-10/ab09358e-8bfb-43f9-a7b4-bd74536197e8?page=2)**

   - The Group Policy has been updated, but I still can't change the lock screen wallpaper.
5. **[Turn off syncing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-change-lock-screen-image-in-windows-10/ab09358e-8bfb-43f9-a7b4-bd74536197e8?page=1)**

   - I actually thought that this would solve my problem, but no.
6. **Open a photo using the Photos app and in the menu at the upper-right, select "Set as", then choose "Set as lock screen"**

   - It just showed a dialog box saying "Try a different photo".

Comment: Can you create a new user (local admin) then change the background in the new user profile - Does this work?